# Организовывает или организует

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, выбор-слов

Я видела в подобном вопросе написали, что "Организовывает" выходит из активного употребления...а как правильно?

Заведующий отделением организовывает/организует работу отделения, осуществляет регулярный контроль за качеством работы сотрудников.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это взаимозаменимые глаголы: правильно и организовывает работу, и организует работу.

Из Малого академического словаря:

> ОРГАНИЗО́ВЫВАТЬ, организо́вывал, -ла, -ло; несов., перех. **То же, что организовать**.